# Protracto-TypeScript Error: Argument type boolean not assigned to parameter type boolean

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor

I am new to typescript and don't know how to debug this error which am getting  in my page object code. Here is the error which typescript is throwing:

`Error:(101, 50) TS2345:Argument of type '(isEnabled: boolean) => Promise<CloudletPolicyBean> | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '((value: boolean) => CloudletPolicyBean | IThenable<CloudletPolicyBean>) | undefined'.`

My Code:

```
    import {ClType} from "./ClType";
    export class ClPolicyBean {
    private type: ClType;
    private name: string;
    private description: string;

    public setType(type: ClType): void {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public getType(): ClType {
        return this.type;
    }

    public setName(name: string): void {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public getName(): string {
        return this.name;
    }

    public setDescription(description: string): void {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public getDescription(): string {
        return this.description;
    }
}
```

Page Object:

```
import {browser, element, by, ElementFinder,ElementArrayFinder} from "protractor”;
import {ClPolicyBean} from "../dsl/ClPolicyBean";
export class CreateClPolicyDialog{
public constructor() {
    super(true);
}
private createPolicyButton: ElementFinder = element(by.css("button[class *= 'submit-button']"));

public isSubmitButtonEnabled(): wd.promise.Promise<boolean> {
    return this.createPolicyButton.isEnabled();
}
public submit(): wd.promise.Promise<CloudletPolicyBean> {

    return this.isSubmitButtonEnabled().then(isEnabled => {
        if(isEnabled) {

            let cl:ClPolicyBean = new ClPolicyBean();

            this.getSelectedClType().then(type => {
                cl.setType(type);
            });
            return this.createPolicyButton.click().then(() => {
                   ExtendedExpectedConditions.waitForElementNotVisible(this.dialogContainer, 30000);
                   return cl;
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now, in my Page object code TypeScript is complaining when I am trying to use isSubmitButtonEnabled. I am new to typescript any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is `createPolicyButton` defined?

Comment: Edited my code.

Comment: @alecxe can you see what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

`isSubmitButtonEnabled` returns a promise. In `submit` in `if` statement you are trying to check is result of `isSubmitButtonEnabled` true. It is not.

Use something like that:

```
public isSubmitButtonEnabled() {
    return this.createPolicyButton.isEnabled().then((enabledBool) => {
        return enabledBool;
    })
}
```

Comment: I am resolving the promise in submit() using a then. Why resolving it before would make any diff?